# One of two partitions on external Windows hard drive not showing

Tags: mount, windows, hard-disk

I have an old hard drive from a Windows machine it is in an external enclosure connected to my Desktop via USB. It has 2 parititions (D and P) and it is of 2TB capacity. When I connect it to my Linux Mint 20 machine I can only see the P partition (852.4 GB).

Here is part of the the fdisk -l output
[image]

Here is a screen show of what I can see in the file manager:

[image]

As you can see it is not showing the 1.8TB capacity indicated by fdisk, and partition D is missing.

Is there any way I can access the other (D) partition?

Thank you for the help

EDIT: I am adding additional information

```
nicofish@nicofish-desktop:~$ sudo ldmtool create all 
Unable to create volume Volume1 in disk group 0def8774-fd3a-11e9-9800-a0510bb8a8bb: ldm_vol_DESKTOP-SRLPJRS-Dg0_Volume1: Stacking NODE_DEL [verify_udev]
Unable to create volume Volume2 in disk group 0def8774-fd3a-11e9-9800-a0510bb8a8bb: ldm_vol_DESKTOP-SRLPJRS-Dg0_Volume2: Stacking NODE_DEL [verify_udev]
[
]
nicofish@nicofish-desktop:~$ sudo ldmtool scan
[
  "0def8774-fd3a-11e9-9800-a0510bb8a8bb"
]
nicofish@nicofish-desktop:~$ sudo ldmtool show diskgroup 0def8774-fd3a-11e9-9800-a0510bb8a8bb
{
  "name" : "DESKTOP-SRLPJRS-Dg0",
  "guid" : "0def8774-fd3a-11e9-9800-a0510bb8a8bb",
  "volumes" : [
    "Volume1",
    "Volume2"
  ],
  "disks" : [
    "Disk1"
  ]
}
nicofish@nicofish-desktop:~$ sudo ldmtool show volume 0def8774-fd3a-11e9-9800-a0510bb8a8bb Volume2
{
  "name" : "Volume2",
  "type" : "simple",
  "size" : 2207778816,
  "chunk-size" : 0,
  "hint" : "D:",
  "partitions" : [
    "Disk1-02"
  ]
}
nicofish@nicofish-desktop:~$ sudo ldmtool show partition 0def8774-fd3a-11e9-9800-a0510bb8a8bb Disk1-02
{
  "name" : "Disk1-02",
  "start" : 1050411008,
  "size" : 2207778816,
  "disk" : "Disk1"
}
```

As you can see create all does not work though I have been able to find the partition with ldmtool. How would I go around mounting it?

Thanks again

Comment: I think your problem is the LDM... maybe check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22108676/1048799)

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: You have to use third party Windows tools to remove the LDM. There now is a read only driver in Linux, but its still best not to use LDM, even if only Windows. From Linux view LDM
http://mika.soup.io/post/304505086/ldmtool-accessing-Microsoft-Windows-dynamic-disks-from
https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv & 
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ldmtool.1.html & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325331&p=13492758&viewfull=1#post13492758

Comment: I have used ldmtool to find the partition, but I still do not know how to mount it. Create all did not work. I have included my console output as text. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was able to recover the data using TestDisk. I was able to recover most of the files and copy them to an external hard drive.